# How to render child and grand child components both created dynamically

Tags: components, render, dynamically-generated

I create from parent component a child and a grand child component using json data. Child component is well rendered but not the grand child component

I used for child component @ViewChild('question', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container!:ViewContainerRef;
But I don't know how can I define from the parent .ts file a @ViewChild for my grand child component.
How can I do